# The use of HTTPS url in a HTTP website

Tags: javascript, https, ads

I have a website using HTTP protocal, and I want to embed a javascript in my website. However, the javascript is in HTTPS format

```
<script src="https://advertise.com/banner.js"></script>
```

Will it cause any problem? The javascript is responsible for loading out an advertisement. Can this script load successfully on all major browser?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this should cause any problem. Did you try it? Is there an issue?

Comment: This shouldn't cause an issue.Most of the CDNs are via HTTPS links.

Comment: RemyG : It is because I remember a long time ago I have carried out a test which try to run on IE (I forgot which version), and IE refused to load the javascript as it is HTTPS but website URL is HTTP (protocol not match). I will try to test it again and see if it still happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not cause any issue. It's perfectly legit to include secure resources (HTTPS) from an insecure (HTTP) page, but browsers will likely refuse you if do it **vice-versa**.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be an issue; the requested JS resource shall be fetched regardless of the protocol. This is a separate call from the browser and is not via your application server.